# Dynamic typename in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, typename

I'm trying to serialize and de-serialize some data in vb.net. Here's how I serialize the data;

Call the routine;

```
SaveData("Reports", GetType(List(Of reports)), allreports)
```

The sub itself;

```
Private Sub SaveData(ByVal loc As String, ByVal ttyyee As System.Type, ByVal data As Object)
    Dim writer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ttyyee)
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(
        "c:\Data\" & loc & ".xml")
    writer.Serialize(file, data)
    file.Close()
End Sub
```

This seems to work OK. However when I try and do the same thing backwards I get an error. Here's the code;

Calling;

```
LoadData("Reports", GetType(List(Of reports)), allreports)
```

The Sub;

```
Private Sub LoadData(ByVal loc As String, ByVal ttyyee As System.Type, ByVal data As Object)
    Dim reader As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ttyyee)
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(
          "c:\Data\" & loc & ".xml")

    data = CType(reader.Deserialize(file), ttyyee)
End Sub
```

The problem is the `ttyyee` argument that's passed to the function. I get the error:

> type ttyyee is not defined.

I plan on using this serialization and de-serialization for a bunch of different types, so I'd prefer not to state it explicitly, rather pass the type as in the save sub. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `list of` has something to do with it. Did you try creating another class that basically is a `list of reports` and pass that

Comment: @Claudius  The error occurs before I run the code (it wont compile like this).

Comment: Random downvote without a comment....

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I'm curious wether my answer has helped you anything, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `DirectCast` rather than `CType` because unless you need to be able to convert between different objects, `CType` is slower and can in some cases be "dangerous" to use.

Secondly, you could specify the type using [**Generic Types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Generic types are implemented like this:

```
Sub blabla(Of T)(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Where `T` is your generic type (this could have any name, but `T` is the most common). If you want to add multiple you just continue:

```
Sub blabla(Of T1, T2, TKey, ...)(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

So using this you would have to specify the type you want to deserialize to before you pass arguments to the method:

```
Private Sub LoadData(Of T)(ByVal loc As String, ByRef data As T) 'T is the type you want to deserialize to.
    Dim reader As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\Data\" & loc & ".xml")

    data = DirectCast(reader.Deserialize(file), T)
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
LoadData(Of List(Of reports))("Reports", allreports)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I added `GetType(T)` in the code - thanks Plutonix. I also changed the `data` parameter from ByVal to ByRef, this is relevant if you are for example deserializing a structure. For classes it doesn't matter.